# Expected value of $\psi(\sum X_i,\sum X_i^2) $

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_i \sim ^{iid} N(\mu,\mu)$, and $\psi(\sum X_i,\sum X_i^2)=\frac{\sum X_i}{N}-\frac{\sum X_i^2-2(\sum X_i)^2/N+(\sum X_i/N)^2}{N-1}$

In a book I'm reading, it's stated that $E(\psi(\sum X_i,\sum X_i^2))=0$, however, it's not what I get.

Using the following equalities(I derived them,so there might be a mistake somewhere),
$E(\sum X_i)=N\mu$, $E(\sum X_i^2)=N(\mu+\mu^2)$ and $E((\sum X_i)^2)=(N^2-N)\mu^2+N(\mu+\mu^2)$,

I get $\mu+ \mu^2+\mu(N-2+1/N)$. I don't get $0$...

Where did I do a mistake?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @probablyme My mistake, sorry. I've edited it.

Comment: I agree with your equalities, except the last one. I think $E[(\sum X_i)^2] = N\mu+(N\mu)^2$.

Comment: @probablyme My reasoning was $E((\sum X_i)^2)=E(\sum_i \sum_j X_i X_j)=\sum_{i\neq j} E(X_i X_j) + \sum E(X_i^2) =(N^2-N)\mu^2+N(\mu^2+\mu)$ Edit: Ah.. ok got the typo.

Comment: @probablyme but even with this equality, I don't get the zero...

Comment: Are you saying that you agree that it is $N\mu+(N\mu)^2$? I also did not get zero. I think am misunderstanding something about the problem, or the statement is false, meaning there is a mistake/typo in the book.

Comment: @probablyme yes, I agree. This function $\psi$ was given as an example of a measurable function that proved that the usual statistics for $\mu, \sigma^2$ were not complete in the family of $N(\mu,\mu)$

Comment: I don't know that level of math/probability, but what we're doing should work. Though, my guess is you're doing too much work. There is probably a nice trick or observation using that level of math that makes this problem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficult part is $\sum X_i^2-2(\sum X_i)^2/N+(\sum X_i/N)^2$.

I suspect this is supposed to be $\sum_i (X_i - \frac1N \sum_j X_j)^2$ which is $ \sum_i ((X_i - \mu) - \frac1N \sum_j (X_j-\mu))^2 $

Expand to $ \sum_i ((X_i - \mu)^2) -\frac2N \sum_i \left((X_i - \mu) \sum_j (X_j-\mu)\right)+ \frac1{N^2} \sum_i \left(\sum_j (X_j-\mu)^2\right)$ and its expectation is $N\sigma^2 -2\sigma^2 + \sigma^2 = (N-1)\sigma^2$ which, since here $\sigma^2=\mu$, is $(N-1)\mu$

Then $\psi(\sum X_i,\sum X_i^2)= \dfrac{N \mu}{N} - \dfrac{(N-1) \mu}{N-1} =0$ as expected

If you had not had the mean equal to the variance then the result would have been $\mu-\sigma^2$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I think that if you keep the first quadratic, instead of writing all in $X_i-\mu$, it'll be simpler to use the equalities derived above, no?

Comment: I find it easier to write $X_i-\mu$ since I know $E[X_i-\mu]=0$ and $E[(X_i-\mu)^2]=\sigma^2$ and I find it easier to handle distributions with zero mean.  You are correct that it is not necessary